# Question on Series.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I had a question that I cannot solve:

So the question is:

Show that $$\sum\limits_{a=2}^{\infty} \sum\limits_{b=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a^b}$$

converges to $1$.

So right off the bat, I can see since $b > 1$, this is a convergent p-series. Now I'm stuck, I don't have a strategy to attack this problem. I tried to review series but I still cannot come up with an idea.

If anyone could lead me into the right direction, that would be much appreciated. :)

Comment: The inner sum is a geometric series, you can calculate explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:  Since $a$ is always greater than $1$, the inner sum is a convergent geometric series,

$$\left({1\over a}\right)^2+\left({1\over a}\right)^3+\left({1\over a}\right)^4+\cdots$$

Find a formula for its sum, and you're off to the races....

Comment: Perfect. This just made me see what I needed to see. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$\sum\limits_{a=2}^{\infty}\sum\limits_{b=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a^b}=\sum\limits_{a=2}^{\infty}(a^2-a)^{-1}=\sum\limits_{a=2}^{\infty}((a-1)^{-1}-a^{-1})=(1/1-1/2)+(1/2-1/3)+...=1$.

In the first step use the formula for a power series knowing that since $a>1,$ $a^{-n}\to0$. In the second step use partial fraction decomposition. The third step is recognizing it as a telescoping series.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\sum_{a = 2}^{\infty}\sum_{b = 2}^{\infty}{1 \over a^{b}}}$
\begin{align}
\sum_{a = 2}^{\infty}\sum_{b = 2}^{\infty}{1 \over a^{b}}
&=\sum_{a = 2}^{\infty}{1/a^{2} \over 1 - 1/a}
=\sum_{a = 2}^{\infty}{1 \over a\pars{a - 1}}
=\sum_{a = 2}^{\infty}\pars{{1 \over a - 1} - {1 \over a}}
\\[3mm]&=\pars{1 - \half} + \pars{\half - {1 \over 3}}
+ \pars{{1 \over 3} - {1 \over 4}} + \cdots 
\end{align}

> $$\color{#00f}{\large%
> \sum_{a = 2}^{\infty}\sum_{b = 2}^{\infty}{1 \over a^{b}} = 1}
> $$