# Double series convergence (without integrals)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Can somebody help me with double summation problem? I don't know at all how to prove that $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^n}$ converges absolutely.
I would be really glad if somebody helped.

Comment: This has been asked and answered before: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2353942/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1684437/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/715934/42969 – all found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bn%3D2%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%20%5Csum_%7Bk%3D2%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bk%5En%7D%24)

Answer (score 4):

$$
\sum_{k=2}^\infty \sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{k^n}=\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{\frac{1}{k^2}}{1-\frac{1}{k}}= \sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{1}{k(k-1)}= 1$$

Comment: The two $\leq$ signs can be replace by $=$.  (The last series telescopes, since $\frac1{k(k-1)}=\frac1{k-1}-\frac1k$.)

Comment: @saulspatz oh you are right. They are all $=$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $ n\geq 2 $, $ \sum\limits_{k\geq 2}{\frac{1}{k^{n}}} $ converges. And we have : \begin{aligned} \sum_{k=2}^{+\infty}{\frac{1}{k^{n}}}=\frac{1}{2^{n}}+\sum_{k=3}^{+\infty}{\int_{k-1}^{k}{\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{k^{n}}}}\leq\frac{1}{2^{n}}+\sum_{k=3}^{+\infty}{\int_{k-1}^{k}{\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^{n}}}}=\frac{1}{2^{n}}+\int_{2}^{+\infty}{\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^{n}}}&=\frac{1}{2^{n}}\left(\frac{n+1}{n-1}\right)\\&\leq\frac{3}{2^{n}} \end{aligned}

Since $ \sum\limits_{n\geq 2}{\frac{3}{2^{n}}} $ converges, we get that $ \sum\limits_{n\geq 2}{\sum\limits_{k=2}^{+\infty}{\frac{1}{k^{n}}}} $ does also converge (Absolutly since we're dealing with positive terms only).

From the absolute convergence, we can, using Fubini's theorem, switch the order of the summations, to get the value of the sum. As seen in a previous answer, $ \sum\limits_{n=2}^{+\infty}{\sum\limits_{k=2}^{+\infty}{\frac{1}{k^{n}}}}=1 $.